# CSS Background position: fixed; not working

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I can not fix the position of the row background with out fixing the row elements.  My goal is to fix the row's background image so when user scroll the elements move\float over the background rather than move together with.  Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do.. see the image and content flow sample here: https://www.nar.realtor/research-and-statistics

my project is here: https://restoresell.com/

NOTE: when I try to use parallax it doesn't work either.  because to speed the parallax the image is enlarged and gets distorted.

Thank You
Gary

Comment: See [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment), particularly the "fixed" value. It might help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to the containing div:

```
background: fixed;
```

Comment: Thank YOU! for some reason my brain and logic was thinking "position" rather than "background" ...I atte,pted "Position: Fixed;" but should have "Background: Fixed;" .. Thank you kindly.

Gary